# Could not import value Text.asText in elm 0.15

Tags: elm

I have a hello world program in elm 0.15 as,

```
import Text exposing (asText)
main = asText "Hello"
```

On compiling to html using `elm-make h.elm`, it throws error as,

```
Error in basics2.elm:

Import Error: Could not import value 'Text.asText'.
    It is not exported by module Text.
```

Note: i am using `import Text exposing (asText)` and not `import Text (asText)` since elm 0.15 compiler explicitly instructed me to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Graphics.Element.show` instead starting with [elm 0.15](http://elm-lang.org/blog/announce/0.15#faster-text-rendering)

```
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
main = show "Hello"
```